# Char 'apex' C++

Tags: c++, char

I am building a simple program that use dynamic array in C++, the program read a file and after I would find a word and when I find it I change from lower case to upper case.
So to find a word I control `If` after and before there are one space or some punctuation char.

When I control if there is a ' (apex) I have a problem:

`s[i+j-1] == '''`

This is because the second close the first, and the third open another char.

It run if I use the ascii code: `s[i+j-1] == 39`.

How can I write this program without using ascii code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'` needs to be escaped in character literal:

```
s[i+j-1] == '\''
```